# r covariance matrix and correlation matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, multivariate-testing

Hello I am using the data dystrophy from package ipred.
I've used a subset to separate from carriers and normal:

```
carrier = subset(dystrophy,dystrophy$Class == "carrier")
normal = subset(dystrophy,dystrophy$Class == "normal")
```

and I've reduce this data selecting only the patients with 1 visit at the hospital:

```
carrier = subset(carrier,carrier$OBS == "1")
normal = subset(normal,normal$OBS == "1")
```

So now I would like to practice calculating the means vector, covariance matrix and a correlation matrix of the proteins but by separated groups(Class factor).

I 've tried with cor and cov, but I think I am doing something wrong. Any help  would be appreciated. thanks!!

Comment: What is your output when calling `cov` and `cor`. If I recall correctly the inputs of `cov` and `cor` have to be of the class `numeric`, so `factor` will not work.

Comment: To elaborate on the comment of @FloSchmo,   please include the code that you tried to get `cor` and `cov`. It will help us respond to _your_ problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you started. Using your variables, you can get the means for each of the proteins using:

```
sapply(carrier[,6:9], mean, na.rm=T)
sapply(normal[,6:9], mean, na.rm=T)
```

For the correlation and covariance you can use:

```
cor(carrier[,6:9], use="pairwise.complete.obs")
cor(normal[,6:9], use="pairwise.complete.obs")

cov(carrier[,6:9], use="pairwise.complete.obs")
cov(normal[,6:9], use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

The `6:9` part is there to restrict the computation to the proteins and not include other features like Age. The `use="pairwise.complete.obs"` part is there to handle the missing values.

Comment: Yeah! that is what I was trying to obtain. My problem was I've tried to use `cov(carrier,[ ])` with the coma  and selecting a wrong vector.. thank you so much!